# how to access variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using javascript in my html page.

I've defined a variable 'language' in html:

```
<c:set var="language" value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
```

and I would like to use/modify this variable from javascript.

```
function changeLanguage(name) {
       language = "fr";
}
```

how can I do it ?

*What I have tried*
I have a picture in html page and after clicking on it I call this js function. when it's called, variable 'language' should be changed to 'fr' . Maybe it can be done easier. I dont know.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: I have a picture in html page and after clicking on it I call this js function. when it's called, variable 'language' should be changed to 'fr' . Maybe it can be done easier. I dont know. I'm not prof at html and js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here JSTL code is executed at server side and the server sees the JavaScript/Html codes as simple texts. The generated contents from JSTL code (if any) will be rendered in the resulting HTML along with your other JavaScript/HTML codes. Now the browser renders HTML along with executing the Javascript codes. Now remember there is no JSTL code available for the browser.

So you cant use javascript to change value.

Answer (score 0):

Change attributes(var) value(language) using JavaScript

Place this in your HTML Page

**HTML**

```
<c:set id="lang" var="language" scope="session" value="...." scope="...." />
<img src="abc.png" onclick="changelang()" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function changelang(){
        $("#lang").attr("var", "fr");
    }
});
</script>
```

Credit:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_attr_set